# Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}$= $\frac{1}{L}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

In $R$, given that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n}= L,$ prove that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{1}{L}.$

Here is my attempt at the proof.

"We need an $N$: $n>N\implies\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{L}\right|<\epsilon.$

$\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{L}\right| =\frac{|x_n-L|}{|x_n||L|}$

Since $x_n$ is convergent, it is bounded and $\exists$$N_1$: n>$N_1$⟹ |$x_n$|>$\frac{|L|}{2}$

$\implies\frac{1}{|x_n|}<\frac{2}{|L|}$

and since $\lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n}=L,$
$\exists N_2$: n>N_2\implies|x_n$-L|<\frac{\epsilon|L|^2}{2}.$

Now, when $n>\max\{N_1,N_2\},$

(|$x_n$-L|)($\frac{1}{|x_n|}$)
 <($\frac{\epsilon|L|^2}{2}$)($\frac{2}{|L|}$) = $\epsilon|L|$

and then finish the proof my dividing by |L|..."

I'm really new to this style of proof so any nick picky advice or corrections are welcome!

Comment: You'll need that $L\neq 0,$ of course.

Comment: Good catch. other than that does it look ok?

Comment: In addition to $L\neq 0$, you need $x_n\neq 0$. This will be satisfied when $|x_n|>|L|/2$ for example (and $L\neq 0$).

Comment: Would using ≥ instead of > be another way to avoid this?

Comment: Strict versus non-strict inequality is not an issue. What matters is the assumption that $L \neq 0$, because it allows us to eventually bound the absolute value of the terms $x_n$ in the sequence away from $0$.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2605661/171159

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I see that if L=0, then the sequence would blow up.

Comment: @Jungleshrimp How did you get $|x_n-L| < \frac{\epsilon |L|^2}{2}$?

Comment: @guimption since $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=L$, given $\epsilon_0=\frac{\epsilon|L|^2}{2}$ $\exists N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|x_n-L|<\epsilon_0$